# Bootstrap Modal Windows in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a dashboard website in NodeJS and MongoDB. In one of the page, I have to open an image in the modal window. Following is the code of that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Tor Modal Check</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.default.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-tables.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive-tables.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

      <style type="text/css">
          body .modal {
            width: 650px;
            margin-left: -325px;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="mainwrapper">


  <div class="rightpanel">

    <ul class="commentlist">
      <% tor.forEach(function(t){ %>
        <li>
          <img src="images/screenshot/<%= t.screenshot %>" alt="" style="width: 60px;" class="pull-left" />
          <div class="comment-info">
            <h4><a href="<%= t.url %>"><%= t.url %></a></h4>
            <p><strong>Comments: </strong><%= t.comments %></p>
            <div class="container">
              <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= t.modalid %>">Show Screenshot</button>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="<%= t.modalid %>" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title"><%= t.url %></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <img src="images/screenshot/<%= t.screenshot %>" height="100%" width="100%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The problem that I am facing is that not all "View Screenshot" are clickable. After digging a lot, I figure it's because of "rightpanel" div class.

```
/*** MAIN PANEL ***/

.rightpanel { margin-left: 260px; background: #f7f7f7; }
.rightpanel:after { clear: both; content: ''; display: block; }
```

If I remove `margin-left: 260px;` everything works as expected.
Any idea why this is happening and how to overcome it?

PS. This is not the complete code. Only the code that is significant for this question.

**EDIT 1:**
It works perfectly fine when i change `margin-left: 260px` to `margin-left: 150px`.

Comment: For what do you need body .model { margin-left: -325px; } ?

Comment: to center the modal window...width will specify the modal window size and margin-left will put the modal window in the center

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) are already centered and have three sizes (300px for `.modal-sm`, 600px (default) and 900px for `.modal-lg`). But, if you need the width to be exactly 650px, you should set the width of `.modal-dialog`, not `.modal`. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.modal-dialog {
    width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: i am using bootstrap v2.3.1. and it's not compatible with latest bootstrap. I don't have class like modal-lg and modal-sm.

Comment: and changing the width in modal-dialog works...but it doesn't solve the mentioned problem.

Comment: @User1: But you're using Bootstrap v3 markup for your modal. v2 does not have `.modal-dialog` and `.modal-content` classes. See here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Ohhh...yes...that's what wrong with it...i made changes according to bootstrap 2 and it worked..thanks a lot...